# 404 при выполнении запроса с использованием Postman к Restful endpoint

Tags: java, get, glassfish

Я создал динамический веб проект с такими классами:

StockQuoteApplication

```
package lesson33;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("resources")
public class StockQuoteApplication extends Application {
}
```

Класс Stock:

```
package lesson33.service;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@XmlRootElement
public class Stock {
    private String symbol;
    private Double price;
    private String currency;
    private String country;

    public Stock() {
    }

    public Stock(String symbol, Double price, String currency, String country) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.price = price;
        this.currency = currency;
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
}
```

Класс StockService:

```
package lesson33.service;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/stock")
public class StockService {

    @Produces({"application/xml","application/json"})
    @Path("{symbol}")
    @GET
    public Stock getStock(@PathParam("symbol") String symbol) {

        Stock stock = StockServiceHelper.getStock(symbol);

        if (stock == null) {
            return new Stock("NOT FOUND", 0.0, "--", "--");
        }

        return stock;
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public Response addStock(@FormParam("symbol") String symbol,
                             @FormParam("currency") String currency,
                             @FormParam("price") String price,
                             @FormParam("country") String country) {

        if (StockServiceHelper.getStock(symbol) != null)
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).
                    entity("Stock " + symbol + " already exists").type("text/plain").build();

        double priceToUse;
        try {
            priceToUse = new Double(price);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            priceToUse = 0.0;
        }

        StockServiceHelper.addStock(new Stock(symbol, priceToUse, currency, country));

        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

Класс StockServiceHelper:

```
package lesson33.service;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class StockServiceHelper {
    public static void addStock(Stock stock) {
        stocks.put(stock.getSymbol(), stock);
    }

    public static void removeStock(String symbol) {
        stocks.remove(symbol);
    }

    public static Stock getStock(String symbol) {
        return stocks.get(symbol);
    }

    private static Map<String, Stock> stocks = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        generateStocks();
    }

    private static void generateStocks() {
        addStock(new Stock("IBM", 43.12, "USD", "USA"));
        addStock(new Stock("AAPL", 120.0, "USD", "USA"));
     }
}
```

Я задеплоил проект на glassfish4.1. Далее пытаюсь подключиться к нему с помощью Postman по ссылке http://localhost:8080/Lesson33/resources/IBM используя GET запрос. Название моего проекта Lesson33. Выдает ошибку HTTP Status 404 - Not Found

Помогите пожалуйста с проблемой. И еще объясните пожалуйста, где можно посмотреть логи того, как я пробую делать запрос. Не логи glassfish, а другие, как можно отследить где возникла ошибка, сбой.

Answer (score 1):

`lesson33` нигде не указан и еще нужно указать `stock`. В общем как то так:

```
http://localhost:8080/resources/stock/IBM
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?